# Why can't Idea not find sources generated by ANTLR4?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea, antlr4

I have a [project](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/elispt/src/i1/) in which I want to use classes generated by ANTLR4 in a piece of Kotlin code.

In [pom.xml](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/elispt/src/i1/pom.xml), ANTLR4 is configured as follows.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>antlr4</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The generated classes are put into `target/generated-sources/antlr4`:

[image]

`mvn clean package`, `mvn clean assembly`, as well as rebuilding the project in Idea lead to the following error:

[image]

Note that the errors occur only in the Kotlin class [Transpiler.kt](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/elispt/src/i1/src/main/kotlin/com/dpisarenko/deplorable/Transpiler.kt), but not in the [test](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/elispt/src/i1/src/test/java/com/dpisarenko/deplorable/DeplorableParserTest.java).

How can I fix this (make sure that classes generated by ANTLR4 can be used in Kotlin code)?

**Update 1:** After moving the grammar file as suggested by @Bart Kiers and executing `mvn clean antlr4:antlr4`, the errors in Idea disappeared. However `mvn clean antlr4:antlr4 install` still results in [build errors](https://gist.github.com/mentiflectax/c7c0ccf5835109dbab5c6cf084692965):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.4.21:compile (compile) on project elispt: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/dp118m/dev/misc/elispt/src/main/kotlin/com/dpisarenko/deplorable/Transpiler.kt:[9,21] Unresolved reference: DeplorableLexer
[ERROR] /Users/dp118m/dev/misc/elispt/src/main/kotlin/com/dpisarenko/deplorable/Transpiler.kt:[11,22] Unresolved reference: DeplorableParser
[ERROR] /Users/dp118m/dev/misc/elispt/src/main/kotlin/com/dpisarenko/deplorable/Transpiler.kt:[12,21] Unresolved reference: DeplorableParser
```

Comment: Provided that the Maven build also fails I do not see it as an IDE issue. Looks like the Maven needs to be configured differently than it is now. Perhaps Kotlin sources are not configured properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you do the following:

1. move `Deplorable.g4` to `src/main/antlr4/com/dpisarenko/deplorable/` (note that you placed it inside `src/main/antlr4/com.dpisarenko.deplorable/`!)
2. run `mvn clean antlr4:antlr4`
3. if not already done, mark `target/generated-sources/antlr4` as the "Generated Sources Root" (right click it in your IDE and select `Mark Directory as`)

If not, try using the latest ANTLR4 version: `4.9.1` (not just the tool and runtime, but also for `antlr4-maven-plugin`).

Comment: Thanks. The question was about Idea and that part of the problem is solved by your answer. If you have any ideas how to fix the issue from *Update 1*, I would appreciate if you shared them. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Don't know for sure: it could be that the Kotlin compiler expects the generated Java sources to reside inside `src/main/java/com/dpisarenko/deplorable/` instead of `target/generated-sources/antlr4/com/dpisarenko/deplorable/`? Try moving them there by hand once and give `mvn clean antlr4:antlr4 install` another try.